# Identifying a multiple feedback op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter, negative-feedback

[image]

I stumbled upon the circuit above, and am trying to understand what its frequency response would be. I just started learning about filters, but haven't come upon a multiple-feedback topology like this.

The right-hand side op-amp looks like an LP filter, yet the multiple feedback confuses me and I don't understand how to analyze the circuit. Any help, even a few pointers, would be appreciated.

Comment: I see things that look like 3 familiar circuits, combined...but I'm not sure. Why not try using KCL? There are only 5 nodes in the circuit and two are 0. Find Vout/Vin and then see if you can relate it to the schematic.

Comment: Where did the circuit come from? At the moment, it looks like something that has no use but, if you reveal the source, then it might be clearer.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're puzzled by the R5 connection. It's not a feedback path. It's a second input to the right-hand op amp. If it connected to a second input voltage rather than Vin, it would be more obvious.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, \$R_5\$ is not a feedback, it's actually a feed-forward resistor. The analysis of the circuit is pretty simple. Suppose that you have a LP op amp filter (the right side op amp) with two inputs, one through \$R_4\$ and one from \$R_5\$. The input voltage source to \$R_5\$ is \$V_{\text{in}}\$ itself and the voltage to \$R_4\$ is

$$V_{\text{o1}} =-1 \times V_{\text{in}} \times \frac{R_2}{R_1}$$

Then do a KCL on the input terminal of right op amp:

$$\frac{V_{\text{o1}}}{R_4} + \frac{V_{\text{in}}}{R_5} = \frac{V_{\text{out}}}{R_3} + V_{\text{out}} C_1s$$

then substitute \$V_{\text{o1}}\$ in terms of \$V_{\text{in}}\$ and calculate the equation for \$V_{\text{out}}/V_{\text{in}}\$.

At the end you come to an equation like this:

$$V_{\text{out}}\left(\frac{1}{R_3} + Cs\right) = \alpha V_{\text{in}}$$

Note that \$s\$ is the Laplace term equivalent to \$j\omega\$. And \$\alpha\$ is a positive or negative coefficient associated to \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ which can be obtained from the above equations.

Answer (score 2):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQa6W0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
0=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6+\text{I}_8
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

- $$\text{V}_{+_1}=\text{V}_{-_1}=\text{V}_1=0\space\text{V}\tag3$$
- $$\text{V}_{+_2}=\text{V}_{-_2}=\text{V}_3=0\space\text{V}\tag4$$

Hence, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_5\text{R}_6\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = 0;
V3 = 0;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I0 == I1 + I3, I4 == I1 + I2, I7 == I3 + I4, I7 == I5 + I6, 
   0 == I5 + I6 + I8, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I1 == (V1 - V2)/R2, 
   I3 == (Vi - V3)/R3, I4 == (V2 - V3)/R4, I5 == (V3 - V4)/R5, 
   I6 == (V3 - V4)/R6}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, V2, V4}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> (1/R1 + 1/R3) Vi, I1 -> Vi/R1, 
  I2 -> -(((R2 + R4) Vi)/(R1 R4)), I3 -> Vi/R3, 
  I4 -> -((R2 Vi)/(R1 R4)), 
  I5 -> -((R2 R3 R6 Vi - R1 R4 R6 Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 R5 + R1 R3 R4 R6)), 
  I6 -> -((R2 R3 R5 Vi - R1 R4 R5 Vi)/(R1 R3 R4 R5 + R1 R3 R4 R6)), 
  I7 -> (1/R3 - R2/(R1 R4)) Vi, I8 -> -(Vi/R3) + (R2 Vi)/(R1 R4), 
  V2 -> -((R2 Vi)/R1), 
  V4 -> (R2 R3 R5 R6 Vi - R1 R4 R5 R6 Vi)/(
   R1 R3 R4 R5 + R1 R3 R4 R6)}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

$$\text{R}_6=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag6$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_5\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_5+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\left(1+\text{sCR}_5\right)}\tag7$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). So, we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\left(1+\text{CR}_5\omega\text{j}\right)}\tag8$$

So, the absolute value if given by:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_5\left|\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right|}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}_5\omega\right)^2}}=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\space\text{R}_2\text{R}_3=\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\\
\\
\frac{\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}_5\omega\right)^2}}&\text{if}\space\text{R}_2\text{R}_3>\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\\
\\
\frac{\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_1\text{R}_4-\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}_5\omega\right)^2}}&\text{if}\space\text{R}_2\text{R}_3<\text{R}_1\text{R}_4
\end{cases}\tag9$$

And the argument:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\arg\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\right)-\arctan\left(\text{CR}_5\omega\right)=$$
$$
\begin{cases}
-\arctan\left(\text{CR}_5\omega\right)&\text{if}\space\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\ge\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\\
\\
\pi-\arctan\left(\text{CR}_5\omega\right)&\text{if}\space\text{R}_2\text{R}_3<\text{R}_1\text{R}_4
\end{cases}\tag{10}$$

Comment: Thanks for the well motivated downvotes.

Comment: How did you confirm the equations with LTspice? Did you compare by substituting some numerical values? Just curious.

Comment: @anhnha yes, indeed. I also did a bode plot using some values and they gave me the same results.